# (sqlite) how to select rows above and below a certain row? without using thier item_id's

Tags: sqlite

This is what I know:

I can use `WHERE` to select a range of `item_id`'s of my choice (ex. if my "middle" item is item_id = 8, I would put: `WHERE item_id >= 5 AND item_id <= 10`). But there's this scenario where I will be retrieving items from a certain category, and it will cause the `item_id`'s to be out of range (ex. `item_id = 1,5,9,14,22,27,31,39`) and my current `WHERE statement` will no longer work.

is there a way to select items in a range without using their `item_id`'s and just simply their row number in the database. (ie. if I have `item_id = 22` as the middle, I can select  `item_id = 9,14,22,27,31` based on the example above.)

I can't seem to find an existing answer that fits my problem, so I posted this question. Thanks in advance!

EDIT

`and my current WHERE statement will no longer work.`

if I have item 1 through 40, and I pick item 8 as the middle, I would have my WHERE statement like this:

note: this is written in java, using `preparedStatement`

```
    original database:
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4
... 
item 40
    
    WHERE item_id >= (selectedItem -2) AND item_id <= (selectedItem +2)
        
        output:
        item 6
        item 7
        item 8
        item 9
        item 10
```

but, if I have:

```
original database:
item 9
item 14
item 22
item 27
item 31
item 40

WHERE item_id >= (selectedItem -2) AND item_id <= (selectedItem +2) // our selectedItem = 22

output:

item 22

// and thats all, because the range is only 20 - 25
```

that's why it won't work

Comment: `and my current WHERE statement will no longer work` ... can you include your current query plus some sample data?

Comment: try IN command. for more you can search in here : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen check edit, thank you so much,.